# Стоит ли код разбивать по файлам?

Tags: python, django

У меня такой вопрос, стоит ли разбивать код по файлам, например:

```
models:
    __init__.py
    user.py
    cart.py
    checkout.py
```

```
views:
    __init__.py
    signin.py
    signup.py
    dashboard.py
```

Или лучше все писать в одном файле ? `models.py, views.py`

Comment: Как вы считаете более удобным, так и делайте. А ещё помните, что Django предусматривает разбивку проекта на несколько Django-приложений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

старайтесь разделять ответственность в django, как пример:
Не приложение, отвечающее за профиль пользователя и корзину покупок, а два django приложения (для профиля и для корзины), вам будет проще переносить код между проектами.
Код вам следует разбивать на разные файлы, но только, если это вам удобно и не противоречит стандартам вашей компании.